# com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, android, http, android-volley

I have got an error. Although there were some solutions out there for java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject, I couldn't solve my problem with the existing solutions.
Here is my Code inside onCreate() of LoginActivity:

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
try{
    jsonObject.put("username",username);
    jsonObject.put("password",password);
    jsonObject.put("isWeb",false);
    jsonObject.put("grant_type","passo");
    jsonObject.put("accepttc",true);
    jsonObject.put("client_id","MyClientMobileApp");
    jsonObject.put("client_secret","myClinet@mobileapp");
    jsonObject.put("devicetype","ios");
}catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Response.Listener<String> responseListener=new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"All went well.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("REsponse: ",response.toString());
    }
};
Response.ErrorListener errorListener=new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Something went wrong...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("REsponse: ",error.toString());
    }
};
LoginRequest loginRequest=new LoginRequest(responseListener,jsonObject,errorListener);
RequestQueue queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(LoginActivity.this);
queue.add(loginRequest);
}
//Code in LoginRequest.java
public class LoginRequest extends JsonObjectRequest {
    private static final String LOGIN_REQUEST_URL ="http://mywebapp.com:8080";
    public LoginRequest(Response.Listener responseListener, JSONObject jsonObject, Response.ErrorListener errorListener){
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQUEST_URL, jsonObject, responseListener, errorListener);
    }
}
```

So far I have been getting response code 200 (success) in android profiler.
But "Something went wrong..." I would like to get "All went well." Any sort of help will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: This means You are expecting JSON response from Service but it is return Html document. fix your service.

Comment: You received `HTML` instead of `JSON` from the server that is why you are getting this error